# asp.net (vb) gridview how to calculate two columns and pass the value to a third column?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm binding my gridview with DB values. I have three columns which are: **Earnings**, **Discount** and **Total**. The Earning and Discount columns are bind with DB values and the Total column is empty. I want to bind the total column with the sum result of the columns (Earnings + Discount).

how can I bind the Total column with the sum result of (Earning + Discount) columns?

**My code**

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Gross_Period1" HeaderText="Earnings" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Disc_Period1" HeaderText="Discount" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total" />
```

Comment: Why not add that as a expression column in the sql?

Answer (score 0):

You can as noted, just include the column in your sql.

However, you can do it this way also:

add column like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Gross_Period1" HeaderText="Earnings" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Disc_Period1" HeaderText="Discount" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total" />
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:label Text='<%#Eval("ID") * 10 %>'  runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

So using "Template" allows you to drop, have, put, place any control of any type into the grid. (in above, you can thus remove the HeaderText total bound field you have.

And you can thus use Eval as a expression.

So, in your case, you could have Text above with this:

```
Text='<%#Eval("Earnings") + Eval("Discount") %>'
```

So that will give the addition of the two columns.